# Installing Mavericks

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, install, leopard

I am installing Mavericks on a 2009 Macbook Pro with an Intel Core 2 Duo using the instructions outlines in this macworld article: 
[The quick and techie way.](http://www.macworld.com/article/2056564/how-to-install-mavericks-over-leopard.html)

So I have a mavericks install drive, but when I go to run it it says this app is not compatible with the arctitecture. The only evidence i could find on this happenening was on PPC macs trying to run intel apps and vice versa.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to clean install OS X Mavericks? If you are, you should download a copy of Mavericks, then restore it onto a external drive, restart your mac onto that install drive, go to Utilities, then to 'Disk Utility' then erase your hard drive. Next, install Mavericks.

If you tried this step and booted with the install drive, I do not know if I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like he is running the installer from the currently installed O/S (?).

If that is the case you may have to create an installer DVD or Flash Drive. There are utilities and terminal commands that will do this rather easily. I prefer the flash drive route and have used it a number of times. There is a freeware utility that works quite well. ArsTechnica has the instructions:

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-9-mavericks-usb-install-drive/